# Shell TAR files from list or using pipe

Tags: shell, tar, broken-pipe

I was trying to pipe a TAR after listing a bunch of files.
First I tried to list my files according to their date. Like this:

```
ll /home/dan/test/dir*/file* | grep 2014
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_100
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_12
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_97
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_98
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  2  2014 /home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_99
```

Since the result is a bit poluted, I tried to filter it.

```
ll /home/dan/test/dir*/file* | grep 2014 | cut -f 2- -d "/" | sed 's/home/\/home/'
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_1
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_10
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_100
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_11
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_12
...
/home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_97
/home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_98
/home/dan/test/dir4/file4_2014_99
```

which gave just file paths and names.
Then I tried to TAR this list using pipe but didn't work out.

So I exported the list to a file

```
ll /home/dan/test/dir*/file* | grep 2014 | cut -f 2- -d "/" | sed 's/home/\/home/' > list_files_2014.txt
```

Now, I need to TAR this list.

But when I try it gives me an error:

```
tar -cvjf test.tar.bz2 -T list_files_2014.txt
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_1
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_10
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_100
/bin/sh: 1: /home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_11
bzip2: not found/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_12

/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_13
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_14
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_15
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_16
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_17
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_18
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_19
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_2
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_20
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_21
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_22
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_23
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_24
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_25
/home/dan/test/dir1/file1_2014_26
tar: test.tar.bz2: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 127
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `bzip2` was not found. Either install it or don't use `-j` option to `tar`

Comment: what is the output of `which bzip2`

Comment: if bzip2 is not  intalled `sudo apt-get install bzip2`

Comment: The main issue is that you need to install bzip2; however, with respect to replacing the `ls | grep` antipattern -- do you have the GNU version of `find`? (If so, you can use a `-newerXY` primitive, like `-newermt`, to find files newer or older than a specific time).

Comment: (btw, bz2 isn't really a good choice these days -- there are algorithms that are faster at the same compression ratio, or which compress much better at the same performance).

Answer (score 1):

You should not parse `ls` because the output of `ls` is not stable and only meant to be read by humans.  After an update of the OS this output (its format) can change, rendering your script buggy.  The link @Cyrus provided leads to a way more exhaustive explanation which I don't want to repeat here.  Anyway, it is way better to use other Unix tools to achieve your goals, e.g. `find`.

But this is not your issue here.

Your issue is merely that your `tar` tries to spawn a second process for the compression you have chosen.  It tries to execute a program called `bzip2`.  This doesn't seem to be installed on your computer, so it fails.  The message comes a little delayed, because first the second process is created, and this parallel running other process then tries to run the program `bzip2`.  In the meantime the `tar` process already started packaging the files (and made some log messages).  Since the two processes are connected by a pipe, the first process finally receives a SIGPIPE when it tries to write into this pipe (which now lacks the reader process).

So you either have to install `bzip2` or you just choose another compression algorithm which already is installed.  You could choose `gzip` by replacing the option `-j` by the option `-z`, for example.  The man page of `tar` names a bunch of other supported compression algorithms.